# Unity - Sort List of Dictionaries after lowest value in Dictionaries

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have a List of Dictionaries in my Unity application looking like this:

```
 public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> offers = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

In this list I store some values from my firebase database and It will look something like this:

```
List[0]
    Store: "storeName"
    Img: "ImageURL"
    Distance: 600
List[1]
    Store: "storeName1"
    Img: "ImageURL1"
    Distance: 30
```

Now I would like to sort my List after lowest "Distance" value, but I can't quite figure out how to use the .Sort() in this context. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did yoiu try OrderBy ? var sortedOffers = offers.OrderBy(x => x.Values.Distance).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OrderBy`:

```
var result = offers.OrderBy(d => d["Distance"]);
```

or if you want to sort in place:

```
offers.Sort((l, r) => ((int)l["Distance"]).CompareTo((int)r["Distance"]));
```